# Is the pronoun "it" gender-neutral pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, gender-neutral, animacy

Is the pronoun "it" a gender-neutral one? If so, then is it okay to use it to refer to *supernatural entities*?

Comment: How could the pronoun it be anything but gender neutral??

Comment: I understand your question. 'They' can be used when a person is involved, but their gender isn't known (or shouldn't be revealed / highlighted). 'It' isn't used for a person; to do so would usually be extremely disrespectful. // I personally would certainly not use 'it' for an angel, say.

Comment: @Lambie By being sex-denying, that's how. Gender-negative pronouns turn living animates into dead objects.

Comment: @DJClayworth Is it not a duplicate? (there are many like it). But it may not be a duplicate since it is about supernatural entities.

Comment: _It_ is not gender-neutral. Rather, it is neuter gender. That's one of the three genders in SAE languages, so it's not gender-neutral, but rather gendered. Grammatical gender has nothing to do with social or biological gender.

Answer (score 3):

The pronoun "it" is indeed gender neutral in the sense of not specifying a gender. However it would be better to describe it as "ungendered", meaning it is applied to entities that don't have gender, rather than one where the gender is unknown. This makes it generally unsuitable for supernatural entities.

The issue is that in virtually all usage "he" is used for male humans "she" for female humans, and "it" for less-than-human entities. "It" implies less-than-human. We see this because it is also normal to call higher-animals, or animals that we love particularly, by "he" or "she" as well. Doing so "promotes" them to human status.

Calling a human "it" is not merely a matter of using a gender-neutral pronoun - **calling a human "it" is insulting, degrading and dehumanizing**. If you want to use a gender-neutral pronoun for a human you would use "they" or a neologism pronoun.

If calling a human "it" is insulting and degrading then the same applies to superhuman entities. It may be OK to refer to a demon or faerie as "it", but if you are referring to somebody's God as "it", be aware that it may be taken as an insult. If you do not mean it to be an insult then I would strongly recommend using another pronoun.

Comment: You've done a good job at explaining that *calling a human "it" is insulting, degrading and dehumanizing*.  One explanation for why this happens is via a model in which "it" is more a **gender-*negative*** pronoun than it is a gender-neutral one. It's not merely "avoiding" stating the sex; it's saying something is sexless, that it has no sex. But it gets worse. It is also a way of saying that the antecedent lacks animacy, that it is a nonliving object not a living sentient being. It denies them agency. It becomes a form of "othering" but worse.  No wonder people shrink from it in disgust!

Comment: @tchrist What I've understood so far is that, "it" has two characteristics. First, it is a **gender-negative** pronoun, i.e, it is used to refer to sexless entities. Second, using "it" to refer to humans has a negative sense, since it is insulting, degrading and dehumanizing. Consequently, it is not apt to use "it" as a pronoun for a supernatural entity. But what if the superhuman enitiy I want to indicate is **indeed** sexless(beyond the concept of gender). In such a case which pronoun would be suitable to use?

Comment: @Tyy A tornado or a flood or a stone can be an *it*. But not living beings with agency of their own. They are animates; they are not a thing. It's not about their sex. It's about their being beings.

Comment: Not exactly. It would be fine to refer to an animal as "it", although you can refer to higher animals as "he" or "she.

Comment: Kindly give me an example of calling a human "it"? Which would mean an **object**, neither animal nor human. All I could come up with is, say, a serial killer who caught in the act. One cop says to another: "Just get it outta here."  Isn't that appropriate??

Comment: The question is about supernatural entities in general, not about any particular kind of a supernatural entity. Some supposed supernatural entities are conceived of as person-like, and it would be odd to refer to them as *it*, for the reason stated in this answer, but some (e.g. The Force in the *Star Wars*) are not.

Comment: Let's not forget hermaphrodites. :)

Comment: "It" is generally not considered appropriate for intersex people, or non-binary people, or anyone who doesn't identify as one of the traditional genders (male/female). It is unlikely to be appropriate for human-like hermaphrodites (truly hermaphroditic people don't exist, but but might for supernatural beings).

Answer (score 2):

In general, *it* is used to refer to things that are not persons.

As others have already mentioned, this means that referring to a person with *it* will in many circumstances be viewed as dehumanizing and insulting.

Aside from inanimate objects, *it* can sometimes be used to refer to animals, or even human infants, but both of those usages are variable and may be disapproved of as objectifying. Generally, the use of *it* for animals is most common with "lower animals" that humans don't have emotional connections to, and least likely with "higher animals" that humans are emotionally attached to such as pets, or any animal belonging to a species commonly kept as pets (such as dogs, cats, horses).

The use of *it* with supernatural entities would depend on analogies with the use with mundane entities. There are a wide variety of conceivable "supernatural entities":

- Some are conceptually very similar to humans, such as elves and wizards in Tolkien's *The Lord of the Rings*: in this case, *it* is no more appropriate than it would be to refer to a human.
- Others are more like animals: something like a werewolf or dragon could plausibly be referred to by *it* just as animals can be (even despite having a male or female gender), but this would be less likely if the creature is treated by the narrator as a person (e.g. if it has the power of speech and interacts socially with human beings).
- Other supernatural entities might be viewed as being more similar to inanimate objects or phenomena than to human persons: potentially a spirit or animate force of nature might be referred to as *it.* A ghost might be referred to as *it* if conceived of primarily as a specter or terrifying vision, or might be referred to as *he* or *she* if conceived of as an intelligent being with personhood.

Comment: Why are you repeating that thing about dehumanizing and insulting? I don't get it.  How do you call a person an it, except for the way I did in a very exaggerated example (above)?